# Fabric nonzero return code 137

Tags: python, linux, celery, fabric

I have the following task in fabric, designed to brute force kill all celery workers in an emergency

```
def brute_kill_cel_workers():
    with settings(sudo_user="operatore"):
       sudo("sudo ps aux|grep 'celery worker'|awk '{print $2}'|xargs sudo kill -9")
```

It fails with

```
Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 137 while executing!
```

Why is this? The commnd itself works fine from the an ssh shell as user "operatore" on the server. Or at least how can I get fabric to give me some more information to work with...

I've also tried just `sudo("ps aux|grep 'celery worker'|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9")` and `run("sudo ps aux|grep 'celery worker'|awk '{print $2}'|xargs sudo kill -9")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you killed Celery with SIGKILL (kill -9) you get that return code: 128 + 9 (see [this list of exit codes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)).

If you check the return code when you run that command with ssh, you'll see the code is identical, but just not handled: when you execute `echo $?` (which shows the exit code of the last commend) after executing the command line with ssh, you'll get 137 as well.